# XSLT 3.0: Division into pages with direction

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt, saxon

I have XML that describes a document, I try with XSLT to convert it to an HTML document that is divided into pages (each 'eop' tag indicates the beginning of a page). On each even number page the direction will be rtl and on the odd page the direction will be ltr.
Each page should be divided into two parts, with the title in one part and the content in the other
I tried but what happens is that from 'article' tag works fine but part of the 'eop' tag to the 'article' tag remains the previous settings.

Anyone have a solution?

xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataRoot >
    <eop eId="100"></eop>
    <article>
        <title>article 1</title>
        <content>
            <point>
                <p>aaa</p>
                <p>bbb
                    <eop eId="101"></eop>
                </p>
                <p>ccc

                </p>
            </point>
            <point>
                <p>ddd</p>
                <p>eee</p>
            </point>
            <p>fff</p>
        </content>
    </article>
    <article>
        <title>article 2</title>
        <content>
            <point>
                <p>ggg</p>
                <p>hhh

                </p>
            </point>
        </content>
    </article>
</dataRoot>
```

xslt:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0" >
    <xsl:mode use-accumulators="#all" streamable="no"/>
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:accumulator name="directionByPage" as="xs:string?" initial-value="'dir_rtl'">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="eop" select="if (number(translate(@eId, translate(@eId, '0123456789', ''), '')) mod 2 = 0) then 'dir_rtl' else 'dir_ltr'"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <style type="text/css">
                    .dir_rtl{   text-align: right;   display: grid;    direction: rtl;    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;                   }
                    .dir_ltr{    text-align: right;  display: grid;    direction: ltr;    grid-template-columns: 15% 85%;                   }
                    .page{
                    margin: 7em;
                    background-color: rgb(68,68,68); /* Needed for IEs */
                    
                    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);
                    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgb(68 68 68 / 60%);
                    
                    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30);
                    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30)";
                    zoom: 1;
                    }
                    .page .content {
                    position: relative; /* This protects the inner element from being blurred */
                    padding: 10em 5em;
                    background-color: #ffff;
                    }
                   
                   .eop{padding:4em;}
                    .numPage{padding:2rem 1rem 2rem 2rem;}
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="dataRoot" >
        <div class="page">
            <div class="content">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </div>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="eop">
        <div class="eop">
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        </div>
        <div class="numPage">
              number page:
            <xsl:value-of select="@eId"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="article" >
        <div class="article">
            <div>
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    <xsl:value-of select="accumulator-before('directionByPage')"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </div>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="title" >
        <div class="title">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="content" >
        <div class="content">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="point" >
        <div class="point">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p" >
        <div class="p">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output html:

[image]

We see here that the direction does not change from the beginning of the page but only from the beginning of the article (because the name of the page is divided into grid)
The question is whether there is a possibility that each component will look for the 'eop' that precedes it (even when it is not at the same level in the xml tree)
Or someone has another solution

Comment: So how many "pages" does that input sample have? To which HTML element is each "page" mapped or to which HTML element or structure should each "page" be mapped?

Comment: Total 2 pages, page number 100 and page number 101 (last page not relevant)
Page 100 shows everything from the 'eop / @ eId = 100' to 'eop / @ eId = 101' and page 101 shows everything from 'eop / @ eId = 101' to 'eop / @ eId = 102'.
(Note: in the question I refer only to direction and not page shape ..)

Comment: I kind of think this problem is solvable (in terms of collecting the right nodes) with e.g. `<xsl:template match="dataRoot"><xsl:for-each-group select=".//node()" group-starting-with="eop">` but due to the need to select nodes at any level you then have to take on processing the `current-group()` only output e.g. `descendant-or-self::node() intersect $group`. It is not clear to me, however, where the direction is to be output and whether you want to reconstruct e.g. the two `article` elements that have data for that page. Consider to edit the question and to show the result you want to create.

Comment: Is this an XSLT problem or an HTML/CSS problem? Do you know what HTML you want your stylesheet to generate? If you do, then tell us and it will be easier for us to help. If you don't know what HTML is going to work, then it would be better to focus on designing the HTML before worrying about how to generate it.

Comment: I tried the example you suggested <xsl: template match = "dataRoot"> <xsl: for-each-group select = ".// node ()" group-starting-with = "eop">
It does divide the document into pages but I did not understand how I attribute each component to its group                                                                                                                          I tried to be clearer, and added example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text direction doesn't apply at the article level, but at the level of individual elements within the article, so you will need to specify the appropriate direction `class` on *all* of those elements.

My advice is to add a function which will return the appropriate class name for each element, by finding the immediately-preceding `eop` and checking whether its number is odd or even, then you can call that function from each template to generate the appropriate class.

```xml
<xsl:function name="text:direction">
    <xsl:param name="element"/>
    <xsl:variable name="eId" select="$element/preceding-sibling::eop[1]/@eId"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="
        if (number(translate($eId, translate($eId, '0123456789', ''), '')) mod 2 = 0) then
            'dir_rtl' 
        else 
            'dir_ltr'
    "/>
</xsl:function>
```

Then in every one of your templates, call this function to add the appropriate directional class, e.g.

```xml
<xsl:template match="article" >
    <div class="article">
        <div class="{text:direction(.)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title" >
    <div class="title {text:direction(.)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<!-- etc. -->
```

Note that the name of the function has a namespace prefix; this is mandatory for stylesheet functions. So you'll need to include a  declaration for that namespace e.g. `xmlns:text="my-namespace-uri"` on the `stylesheet` element.